# How to get text of uncertain number of "<p>" tag using scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

How to get text of uncertain number of `<p>` tag using scrapy? as in the following two examples:

Get all `<p>` text after `<h2>XXXX Characteristics</h2>` or `<h3>XXXX Diet</h3>` inside of `<div class="entry-content">`, then merge block of `<p>` to other field, but the number of `<P>` is uncertain.

**Page1**
[image: Page1]
**Page2**
[image: Page2]

Comment: can you post the url?

Comment: https://animalcorner.org/animals/aardvark/
https://animalcorner.org/animals/addax/

Answer (score 1):

You can try extracting all the children of the `div` and perform a regex test to see if it is an `h2` or `h3` then test if the text conatins `"Diet"` or `"Characteristics"` and if it passes collect all siblings with that are `<p>`.

```
def parse(self, response):
    collect = False
    contents = []
    for selector in response.xpath("//div[@class='entry-content']/*"):
        val = selector.xpath("./text()").get()
        if collect and selector.re('<p'):
            contents.append(val)
            continue
        if val and selector.re(r'<h[23]'):
            if "Characteristics" in val or "Diet" in val:
                collect = True
        else:
            collect = False
    yield {"contents" : contents}
```